# How to copy files from HDD to USB Flash Linux Mint

Tags: linux, boot, usb, data-recovery

I'm currently running linux mint on my live USB Boot, and im using TestDisk to get specific files from a corrupt HDD. There was no problems copying them **to the USB with Linux in it**. But whenever i remove the usb stick, the files dissapear.

I tried mounting using

```
mkdir /media/flashdrive1
```

to copy the files there, but i dont know how to keep going

Answer (score 1):

You must either
  1) use a second drive (USB, HDD, SDD, SD card, et al.)  as the destination
- *or* -
  2) boot with a LiveUSB with Persistence. The easiest way to make the latter is with the [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) Open Source app, which [explains persistence](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Do_you_plan_to_add_Linux_persistent_partition_support_eg_for_Ubuntu) (and a lot more).

Be certain to set the Partition Scheme to GPT & the Target System to UEFI (non-CSM) as shown below. The Persistent size depends on the size of the USB flash drive you use, and you can vary it as needed.

[image: Screenshot of Rufus]